# Create custom tax class based on weight

Tags: extensions, tax, overrides, core

in germany there is a special Tax on coffee: 2.19 EUR per 1000 gram, and 4.78 EUR per 1000 gram for instant coffee.

I'd like to solve this problem by adding a custom tax to magento.
How would I do that?

EDIT:

I need to calculate the additional product tax based on the product **weight** instead of the product price.

The product weight may change depending on which (or if any) product options are selected. This is a customer requirement and cannot be changed.

Answer (score 1):

You could modify the existing tax model, but it seems like you are trying to / may have a requirement to display this tax separately. Based on the requirement to display this as part of the totals display, you need to create a custom totals model. [Classy Llama have a great series on this rather involved process.](http://www.classyllama.com/blog/unravelling-magentos-collecttotals-introduction).

As a summary, you'll need to do the legwork to register your collector and, if you like, use a separate calculation model or just bake yours into your collector. You can grab the products from the address and perform the calculation you need.

Answer (score 0):

please go through with the magento knowledge base for this.

http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/ce18-and-ee113-setup-taxes-step3

Comment: The problem is that (AFAIK) magento can only work with fixed or percental taxes based on the product *price*. I need to calculate the taxes based on the product *weight*.

Comment: @keks : you have to create tax on shipping for this.
have a look on the link
http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/setting-up-tax-on-shipping

Comment: Thanks for your help, but this does not meet my customers requirements. My customer does not want increased shipping costs to german customers, he wants to display the extra-tax enforced on him by german tax rules.

Comment: I thought about writing a module to do this, but I don't know which classes/methods i need to override, yet. Any hints? Taxes are calculated in several places like product overview, product details, cart, checkout, ...

Comment: look at this http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/1735/

here you find a batter answer for which file you have to override.

Comment: Looks like I need to override a lot of methods there, which would definately cost too much time and probably break with future updates... Is there no easier way to do this? All I want to do is to add a custom tax/fee where I can define the calculation myself.

Comment: I also have to do R&D for this..
give me some time I will get back to you..

Comment: did you find out anything useful?

Comment: not yet my friend. Sorry :(

Answer (score 0):

A little late to party here but you can setup a Shopping Cart Sales Rule based on weight, you will have to first go to the attributes and change the promotions rule restriction on the weight attribute to yes

[image]